# Source code to retrieve Google Adsense earnings?

Tags: c#, php

Where to find source code to read google adsense account earnings ? any language welcome especially c#, php.

Update: I still don't have any source code until now that seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this php library http://code.google.com/p/php-adsense-account-library/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately all of the other answers are using either deprecated API or are linking to 404 pages.

Google did release a new management API for AdSense which is well documented:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/developer/index.html)  It's a very in-depth webservice that allows you not only to get access to reporting, but also create, modify, etc campaigns.

[This](http://planetozh.com/blog/my-projects/track-adsense-earnings-in-rss-feed/) is an interesting low-tech approach.  It's featured on the CURL website.  Could be re purposed for your application.

Comment: Are you sure the curl code still works ? I tried without success.

Comment: "The AdSense API enables developers  to programmatically generate ad code snippets for insertion into a publisher's  web pages." I don't want to generate ads but show MY earnings not other's earnings.

Comment: Indeed, it does that too, see the reports section of the documentation.  You might also pick apart the CURL method to better understand how they're doing it.

Comment: I'm not a publisher just a standalone blogger am I authorized to use Adsense API ?