# Google AdSense monitor android app

Tags: android, authentication, monitor, adsense

I thought that i can use oauth to login to my AdSense account page to view how much i've earned today, but it seems that AdSense is not in [oauth list](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/)

duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683105/google-adsense-for-android) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937975/source-code-to-retrieve-google-adsense-earnings)

htt_p://www.adsensefeed.info/ provide exactly what i want, but i just don't understand how to get to adsense account by myself. Help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google [AdSense management API](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/) uses oauth2. Check [TinyMonitor](http://tinymonitor.com/). It uses this API to download data and it generates also RSS feeds.